# On click change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have created a navigation and I want that each category that a user will click to get the CSS of the button related to it.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/14/

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #fefcea;
    background: #4c4c4c;
}
#nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}
#main {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Day</li>
        <li>Night</li>
        <li>Nature 1</li>
        <li>Nature 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol alittle bit i don't know how to select li text so i don't really know how to start

Comment: [Here's my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/18/), but I'll leave it as an exercise to you to try and understand it ;)

Comment: @alonblack - you are missing jQuery in your fiddle as well...answer with $('#nav ul li').click(function(){ should be ok

Comment: I don't see why JS is required here. Use either the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) (to style the clicked link) or [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) (to style the link target within one page) CSS pseudo classes.

Comment: @feeela like this? nth-xhild(1):target{ background-color: blue;}

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But what if i want to use picture and not color?

Comment: Well, you can use a similar attribute to store a background image URL, and use `style.backgroundImage` to apply it.

Comment: @alonblack Yes, if you want to set this for the first menu item only. Please read the linked documentation to see what is necessary to get this working.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Can u plz show me 1 example i didn't got how to use it

Comment: @feeela but how can i target the change to the "main" div? and not to the "li" itself?

Comment: @alonblack Sorry, but no. The code I have given you is practically plain English ("on click", "get element by ID", "style background colour", "get attribute", etc.) it should not be that difficult ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it's about where to put it... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this , this will only affect the current clicked one

```
$('#nav ul li').click(function(){
     $('li').removeClass('bc');
    $(this).addClass('bc');
});
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/29/)

Comment: thanks! 1)i want to change the color of the "main" div 2) what if i want to change it to a pic and not to a color?

Comment: You can do that using background-image, for main div background color check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/37/

Comment: how can i target each different li "day" "night" ... to a different background?

Comment: i have tried to make a third click can u pleas see why it's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/55/

Comment: U have given 'nature1' instead of "Nature1"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41023/discussion-between-bharath-rallapalli-and-alonblack)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add js like "jquery 1.10.1" and also add in html one attribute under li.

Here is html code:

```
  <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li data-color="red">Day</li>
                <li data-color="gray">Night</li>
                <li data-color="yellow">Nature 1</li>
                <li data-color="blue">Nature 2</li>

            </ul>        
        </div>
    <div id="main"></div>
```

Here is js code :

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){
   var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
    $(this).css( "background-color", color );
});
```

Comment: but what if i want to add pic at the background?

Comment: Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hk/68/ 
In html you have to add correct path of image  "<li data-image="images/day.png">Day</li>". you have to add your path inplace of "images/day.png".

Comment: i want to combine 2 of the first links will be colors and the last two will be images